# firestore set with merge true override object

Tags: javascript, firebase, merge, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have a document with the folowing data (no subcollections)

```
"kdsjkasdlkfsalk" : {
    favouriteColor: "brown",
    age: 20,
    content: {
      rand1: "randAns1",
      rand2: "randAns2"
    }
 }
```

Now I want to change `favouriteColor` and overwrite `content` without changing `age`. Therefore I use:

```
ref.set({
      favouriteColor: "blue",
      content: {
        newRand: "newRandAns",
        newRand2: "newRandAns2"
      },
    }, {merge:true})
```

The wanted result:

```
"kdsjkasdlkfsalk" : {
    favouriteColor: "blue",
    age: 20,
    content: {
      newRand: "newRandAns",
      newRand2: "newRandAns2"
    }
}
```

The actual result:

```
"kdsjkasdlkfsalk" : {
    favouriteColor: "blue",
    age: 20,
    content: {
      newRand: "newRandAns",
      newRand2: "newRandAns2",
      rand1: "randAns1",
      rand2: "randAns2"
    }
}
```

As you can see `{merge:true}` prevents the overwriting of `content` and instead just adds new fields.

I can think of 2 solutions, but they either involve first retrieving all of the data, or first setting `content` to a boolean and then setting it to the wanted object. Is there a better way to get the wanted result?

Comment: Check my updated answer]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `set`

You can use `update` on

```
"kdsjkasdlkfsalk" : {
favouriteColor: "brown",
age: 20,
content: {
  rand1: "randAns1",
  rand2: "randAns2"
  }
}
```

You want to do this because you're providing new properties to `content`. `rand1 vs newRand`

Merge will merge the new properties into the existing object.

Update Example (dot notation)

```
firebase.firestore().collection("someCol").doc("kdsjkasdlkfsalk").update({
    "color": "someNewColor",
    "content.rand1": "someNewRandValue",
    "content.rand2": "someNewRandValue"
});
```

or

```
const content = {
    rand1: "someNewRandValue",
    rand2: "someNewRandValue"
}

firebase.firestore().collection("someCol").doc("kdsjkasdlkfsalk").update({
    "color": "someNewColor",
    content
});
```

Comment: update do not create the document if it do not exists. That's the hole point of `.set( {merge: true})`

Answer (score -1):

Your actual code after changing the color:

```
var obj = {
  favouriteColor: "brown",
  age: 20,
  content: {
    rand1: "randAns1",
    rand2: "randAns2"
  },
 {merge:true}
}
```

You can clean the content property

`obj.content = {};`

And the the new values

```
obj.content.newRand = "newRandAns";      
obj.content.newRand2 =  "newRandAns2";
```

And then set you `obj` object to Firebase
`ref.set(obj)`